# Generate random password for one-time password verification

Tags: c#, validation, forgot-password

I had to generate random password for temporary entry/login purpose in C#. Now I need to only send 6 digits but no more characters, or special characters. New to the C# world. Hence, I am providing what I have so far.

helper.cs

```
public static string GenerateRandomPassword()
{
    int numsLength = 6;
    
    const string nums = "0123456789";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < charLength; i++)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(chars.Length);
        sb.Append(chars[index]);
    }
    int numindex = rnd.Next(nums.Length);
    sb.Append(nums[numindex]);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I think my logic is still not right. I know that I should not use String Builder since I only want to send digits. Can anyone help me and figure out my mistake by editing the above codes?

Comment: In response to " I should not use String Builder since I only want to send digits" no - this is perfectly fine because you are assembling a string at the end of the day. Its perfectly valid here. Generally, if I see its going to be over 10 operations on a string I use sb, because that's when you really start seeing the gains in efficiency. Since you are doing 6 string operations, its not *necessary* but also not *wrong*. To be honest, I would say leave it as is because if the requirement ever changes, it will be a tiny bit less refactoring

Comment: `Random` is not cryptographically safe, that's why it should not be used in password generating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just concatenate strings and do something like:

```
public static string GenerateRandomPassword()
{
    int numsLength = 6;

    const string nums = "0123456789";
    string tempPass = string.Empty;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 1; i <= numsLength; i++)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(nums.Length);
        tempPass += nums[index];
    }

    return tempPass;
}
```

Comment: I will try this logic, seems like good fit. I will sure post feedback if it worked or need to change anything else. Hang tight. Thank you for now.

Answer (score 2):

Try to generate random numbers directly and convert them to a string, rather than to select random characters from an existing string, this will simplify your code

```
Random rnd = new Random();

public static string GenerateRandomPassword()
{
    int numsLength = 6;
    string sixDigitString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < charLength; i++)
    {
        //this takes the existing string and adds a random number to it. Do this as many times as you need to
        sixDigitString += rnd.Next(0,9).ToString();
    }
    return sixDigitString;
}
```

Comment: Putting aside that `Random` shouldn't be used for anything security related, instantiating a new `Random` object inside a method, depending on the target runtime, is either detrimental or sub-optimal.

Comment: While i do agree with you i do not expect a question as basic from people doing security, i guess this is going to be suffcient for his purpose and not confuse him to much

Comment: I agree 100%, just thought I'd bring it up for the sake of the OP.

Comment: Loop is an expensive solution to this problem. Also, it is better to work with `numbers` instead of `tostring() for each character`

Answer (score 2):

Since Random is not cryptographically safe and Microsoft recommends using RandomNumberGenerator, you can do following to get a cryptographically strong random PIN number:

Method:

```
static int GeneratePIN(int start, int stop)
{
    return RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(start, stop);
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("Random PIN: {0}", GeneratePIN(100000, 1000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Random rnd = new Random();
  String passSixDigit = rnd.Next(0, 999999).ToString("000000");
```

Comment: this will take away his ability to change the digit count but other than that gets the job done